# How to update input value when assigning onChange event in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am having problems with the total number of items in the CartHeader component. Obviously I have added the quantity of each product but the result is not as I expected ?. Can someone find the fault for me? I sincerely thank.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CartHeader from "./CartHeader";
import CartBody from "./CartBody";
import CartFooter from "./CartFooter";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Apple Watch Series 5",
          description: "Description for Apple Watch Series 5",
          img:
            "https://bachlongmobile.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/2/0/2076130625_1_1_1.jpg",
          price: 499.99,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
          description: "Description for iPhone 11 Pro Max",
          img:
            "https://cdn.fptshop.com.vn/Uploads/Originals/2019/9/11/637037687763926758_11-pro-max-xanh.png",
          price: 1099.99,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Macbook Pro 16 inch",
          description: "Description for Macbook Pro 16 inch",
          img: "https://shopdunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/mac16inch.jpg",
          price: 2399.99,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "iPad Pro 12.9 inch",
          description: "Description for iPad Pro",
          img:
            "https://cdn.fptshop.com.vn/Uploads/Originals/2019/1/11/636828015979564724_ipad-pro-12-9-xam-1.png",
          price: 999.99,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "AirPods Pro",
          description: "Description for AirPods Pro",
          img:
            "https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/MWP22?wid=1144&hei=1144&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&op_usm=0.5,0.5&.v=1572990352299",
          price: 249.99,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  onRemoveProduct = id => {
    const newProducts = this.state.products;
    // Tìm vị trí sản phẩm cần xoá
    let index = newProducts.findIndex(product => product.id === id);
    // Kiểm tra nếu tìm thấy thì mới xoá
    if (index !== -1) {
      newProducts.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({
        products: newProducts
      });
    }
  };

  handleChange = (e, id) => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    const indexProduct = products.findIndex(product => product.id === id);
    products[indexProduct].quantity = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ products });
  };

  render() {
    const products = this.state.products;
    let numberItems = 0;
    let subTotal = 0;
    products.map(product => {
      numberItems += product.quantity;
      subTotal += product.price * product.quantity;
    });

    return (
      <main>
        <CartHeader numberItems={numberItems} />
        <CartBody
          products={products}
          onRemoveProduct={this.onRemoveProduct}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <CartFooter subTotal={subTotal} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

have I ever misunderstood the problem.
Link codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-hill-6w2ex

Comment: Please provide how you tried to solve this problem and why you was not succeded, this question looks more like task rather than question

Comment: @DmitryReutov thank you for comment. I have learned and fixed this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define curry function for `handleChange` method like below:

```js
  handleChange = id => e => {
    const {products} =  this.state;
    const indexProduct = products.findIndex(product => product.id === id);
    products[indexProduct].quantity = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ products: [...products] });
  };
```

inside CardBody:

```js
  <input
      type="number"
      className="quantity"
      step={1}
      defaultValue={product.quantity}
      onChange={e => handleChange(product.id)(e)}
      />
```

Here you can find [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-mirzakhani-bbb28)

Comment: Nearly identical to my solution. One suggestion, shallow copy `this.state.products` array to mutate and return. Don't mutate and return existing array, this can lead to render issues.

Comment: nice catch @DrewReese. fixed.

Comment: `products` is an array, not an object. `this.setState({ products: [...products] });` Though I usually prefer to copy first, then mutate the copy.

Comment: Why curry when you can just pass the `id` as another parameter? `handleChange(e, id) => ...`

Comment: @DrewReese is still working with {...products} any thought?

Comment: Try this solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-star-k7g0l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @tobiasfried I rather curry because if you fix an id and get a function that only does changes on that id. it's more extendable in my opinion but here you are right the second argument can do the work.

Comment: Objects *are* associative arrays of key-value pairs, so you are technically spreading in this { 1: { product 1}, 2: { product 2}, ...}. The keys are array indices, the values are the array elements. It works, but isn't quite as clear.

Comment: @tobiasfried the "currying" is acting as a Higher Order Function, it is a function that takes an `id` parameter and returns a handler function with the `id` enclosed in its scope. It is bound and runs once when the component mounts versus each time when the component renders. Lookup arrow function binding and `this`.

Comment: @DrewReese wait what? Don't you want it to run when the component rerenders, like for example when you type in a new quantity? I understand what the curry does, but fail to see what is gained besides passing only one argument vs. two.

Comment: @tobiasfried You want the callback to be called *when* the event happens. Binding functions once on-mount (first render) is just a performance enhancement over binding on each subsequent render. The "curried" function runs and returns the *actual* event callback function. Don't worry, if this is confusing or doesn't make sense, the other way of passing both `event.target.value` and `id` works nearly as well.

Comment: @DrewReese OK, I think I see. Out of curiosity, how does the binding process know how far to call the function when binding? If for the sake of example you had an HOF like `curriedFunction(with)(many)(levels)`, would this be evaluated up to the final call, and bound as `curriedFunctionWithMany(levels)`?

Comment: @DrewReese I checked 0bject spreading again and it completely wrong. it only helps to rerender but not update products state at all. thanks again.

Comment: @tobiasfried getting a little off topic, but it is evaluated for as many of the functions as you call with parameters. i.e. for function `const curried = a => b => c => {}`, if it is called as `curried(1)` it returns `b => c => {}`, it called as `curried(1)(2)` it returns `c => {}`, and if called with all 3, `curried(1)(2)(3)` it returns whatever is evaluated in the final function body.

Comment: In the case above with the event handler we're essentially leaving the function `e => { callback(savedId, e); }`. The simpler use is to **not** bind another inline function and simply set the handler **to be** the result of the HOF since its signature matches that of the `onChange` handler, i.e. `e => void`, we can do this `onChange={handleChange(product.id)}`. Here maybe it is a little clearer we're calling the function right away and saving its result to be the actual callback used.

Comment: @Alireza There is still a little problem here when the total number of items is not displayed as expected.

Comment: @tobiasfried Your solution also has problems when the total number of items is not displayed correctly

Comment: @Thien Fixed. It was adding the String representation of the quantities rather than the Number representation.

Comment: @tobiasfried Thank you. I have also fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic data display is best accomplished through the React state. At the moment, you define variables within the `render()` function, but this area is largely for static data.

First, define the numerical values (quantity and total) as state values instead of variables. Then, define a function that handles the `onChange` event of each quantity input for each product. In that function, handle the accumulation of each numerical value and subsequently update the state with those values.